# How to add the filename as prefix to each line of the text file? (batch processing; subdirectories)

Tags: find, sed, awk

I have many .txt files with their filenames being different dates:

```
01.01.2010.txt
02.01.2010.txt
...
```

Currently each file (e.g.: 01.01.2010.txt) looks like this:

```
  0.351  XXX  XXX  XXX  XXX
  0.292  XXX  XXX  XXX  XXX
```

---

**How do I add the filename to each line of the file and keep the format?**

... so it looks like this, for file 01.01.2010.txt:

```
  01.01.2010  0.341  XXX  XXX  XXX  XXX
  01.01.2010  0.122  XXX  XXX  XXX  XXX
```

.. and looks like this, for file 02.01.2010.txt:

```
  02.01.2010  0.391  XXX  XXX  XXX  XXX
  02.01.2010  1.342  XXX  XXX  XXX  XXX
```

These files are stored in subdirectories. If there is a one-liner that can process all of them and also the subdirectories, it would be awesome.

```
- /patch/to/file
 -/path/to/file/sub1/
 -/path/to/file/sub2/
 -/path/to/file/sub3/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest using `bash` loops and `sed`. For example:

Create a test file set:

```
$ for i in $(seq -w 1 10); do echo $i-content > $i.txt; done
```

Assemble the replacment command:

```
$ for i in *.txt; do sed -i.bak s/^/$(basename $i .txt)\ /g $i; done
```

Combine it with `find`:

```
for i in $(find /your/source/directory/ -iname "*.txt" -print)
do sed -i.bak s/^/$(basename $i .txt)\ /g $i; done
```

This was not optimized for performance, and is therefore likely not the most efficient way of doing the requested task.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
grep -r . .
```

The first `.` is RegExp patern matching any character. It will match all lines.

The second `.` is for the current folder, but you can replace it with any valid path. E.g.:

```
grep -r . /etc/
```

Comment: This is much simpler than the accepted answer and works great!